# Go on Google App Engine has Frequent Shutdowns

Tags: google-app-engine, go, nginx

We have a mobile application running off go on Google app engine. We suddenly started having issues with random shut downs from 16th October 2019. First we saw 5xx errors and increased the minimum instances.  Then the error started showing up as container called exit(1). And now, it has changed to terminated process with error exit status 1.

[Error log from nginx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzsnv.png)

This is our current app.yaml setup:

```
runtime: go111
env: standard
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 35
  max_instances: 35
  min_idle_instances: 5
  max_idle_instances: 5  # default value
  min_pending_latency: 300ms  # default value
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_concurrent_requests: 50
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.8
```

The Nginx.conf file

```
events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 650;
  keepalive_requests 10000;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # Logs will appear on the Google Developer's Console when logged to this
  # directory.
  access_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;
  error_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  server {
    # Google App Engine expects the runtime to serve HTTP traffic from
    # port 8080.
    listen 8080;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
}
```

The application log before the latest shutdown:

```
2019-11-18 00:30:41.815 EAT
{"textPayload":"","insertId":"5dd1bc01000c72b428121c93","resource":{"type":"gae_app","labels":{"project_id":"gumzo-backend-223809","version_id":"20191114t210636","module_id":"default","zone":"us6"}},"timestamp":"2019-11-17T21:30:41.815796Z","labels":{"clone_id":"00c61b117ceb00f18aae14afcc55fa0fe6…
 
{
 insertId: "5dd1bc01000c72b428121c93"  
 labels: {
  clone_id: "00c61b117ceb00f18aae14afcc55fa0fe65cfc93726dd8a793451bb6d9c4181ec5fc32"   
 }
 logName: "projects/gumzo-backend-223809/logs/stdout"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-11-17T21:30:42.163592840Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   module_id: "default"    
   project_id: "gumzo-backend-223809"    
   version_id: "20191114t210636"    
   zone: "us6"    
  }
  type: "gae_app"   
 }
 textPayload: ""  
 timestamp: "2019-11-17T21:30:41.815796Z"  
}
2019-11-18 03:15:22.550 EAT
Container called exit(1).
 
{
 insertId: "5dd1e29a000864b036cdfc81"  
 labels: {
  clone_id: "00c61b117ced9f166f1fc9560966f8c22ba2187c3d884e466556f0d93d1beb9d7be735db63"   
 }
 logName: "projects/gumzo-backend-223809/logs/varlog%2Fsystem"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-11-18T00:15:22.555202950Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   module_id: "default"    
   project_id: "gumzo-backend-223809"    
   version_id: "20191114t210636"    
   zone: "us6"    
  }
  type: "gae_app"   
 }
 severity: "WARNING"  
 textPayload: "Container called exit(1)."  
 timestamp: "2019-11-18T00:15:22.550012017Z"  
}
```

Anyone know on how we can keep the application running without multiple shutdowns? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your app is crashing. where are the application logs?

Comment: @TravisWebb I have added the application log file.

Answer (score 0):

add [warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuring-warmup-requests) to your App.yaml file:

```
inbound_services:
- warmup
```

Also, I suggest you change **[the target_cpu_utilization:](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#automatic_scaling_target_cpu_utilization) 0.6** (which is the default). This will let your instances to start serving as soon as the CPU usage reaches 60%. This will increase your App performance but increase cost.